# How to compare the epoch time with current time in python?

Tags: python, time

I would like to compare the output of the created time file with the actual time

```
import os.path, time
print "created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file))
#Tue Apr 8 09:34:33 2014

print "created: %s" % os.path.getctime(file)
#1396965031
```

Is possible to do somethng like that:

```
if os.path.getctime(file) < 100 #eg file older than 100 seconds
do something
```

Thanks

Comment: Save it in a variable for future references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do like:

```
>>> created = os.path.getctime(filename)
>>> now = time.time()
>>> if now - created > 100:
    print "Haha"
```

Or in short form:

```
>>> if time.time() - os.path.getctime(filename) > 100:
    print "Haha"
```

In both cases, you need to compare the file's create time with the **current** time. In addition, **file** is a keyword in Python. So try NOT to use it as a variable name.

Hope the post be helpful!